# asp.net mvc where to set default culture?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, multilingual, culture

For multilingual asp.net mvc web site.

Where should i set thread's culture to default language (which is tr-TR for my case), in addition i need to save this in cookie if it does not exists. in Application_Start() or else ?

I have multiple sites(domains), so i need to change default language site specific.

```
 example.com must set default culture to tr-TR
 example2.com must set default culture to en-US
```

Answer (score 5):

Try it setting in  web.config

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <globalization uiCulture="en-GB" culture="en-GB" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

this is a more generic way to set the culture...

Comment: To make it even more generic, you can use this to automatically detect the culture of your browser : <globalization culture="auto" uiCulture="auto" enableClientBasedCulture="true" />

Comment: I need to set default culture based on site (domain) , so is it the proper way to set culture in webconfig ? I updated the question above.

Comment: i am not very sure but there is a easy way where route can be added in Routeconfig class

foreach (var route in routes.Cast<Route>().Where(route =>
 route.GetType() == typeof(MultiLingualRoute)))
             {
                 route.Url = "{language}/" + route.Url;
                 route.Defaults.Add("language", "YOUR-DEFAULT");

             }

this might give u a a hint .

Answer (score 1):

You can set culture in  Application_AcquireRequestState:

```
protected void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // A Cookie
    string cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["culture"].Value;

    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(cookie);
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(cookie);
}
```

You can also visit this  [link](http://codekea.com/3RXjEJ6yVgNP/set-culture-in-an-aspnet-mvc-app.html)