# DatePicker With only English language

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datepicker, data-annotations

I am using ASP.net MVC Razor Syntax and i have a "BirthDate" in the Model and i takes it as input from the view using date picker, it works fine but when the browser language changed the datepicker changes also but i want it still English all the time but i don't know ho to do that.
This is the Definition of "BirthDate" with it's Data annotation:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> BirthDate { get; set; }
```

and this is the line of code I'm using in the View :

```
<div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BirthDate, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BirthDate)
                          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BirthDate)
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Your `EditorFor()` method generates `<input type="date" ... />` which renders the browsers HTML-5 datepicker. You have no control over this. And in any case its only supported in Chrome and Edge. In FireFox and IE it will just generate a normal textbox. Use a jquery datepicker plugin.

Answer (score 0):

you can change it in web.config

```
configuration>
    <system.web>
        <globalization uiCulture="en-GB" culture="en-GB" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

see [link to other question on stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32602713/asp-net-mvc-where-to-set-default-culture) for more information.

Comment: I tried that but nothing changed , i still have the problem.